# WhatsApp messages disappeared without having been deleted

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery

I was texting like normal yesterday morning when all of a sudden it said WhatsApp is not responding or something like that, but after it came off EVERYTHING was deleted, even my backup. I had messages from 2016 there. What should I do to recover my lost messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled `Google Backup` in `Whatsapp`. You can have your messages back. For this you have to start `Whatsapp` from beginning and re verify your phone number and if you have any `Whatsapp backup` in your google Drive `Whatsapp` will automatically restore it for you.